# Hardcode login credentials in c# for trello api

Tags: c#, authentication, credentials, trello, trello.net

I've been using trello.net api for trello to read through the boards etc.

I've been using the `trello.GetAuthorizationUrl();` to redirect the user to a login page for trello although I'm looking for an option where I can just hard code my login credentials into the C# code.

Let me know if anyone has done that or knows how to.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of hardcoding the credentials, you could hardcode the token.

Visit this url (replace some parameters first):

```
https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey&name=My+Application&expiration=never&response_type=token&scope=read,write
```

Hardcode the token you get back and do:

```
trello.Authorize(hardcodedToken);
```

(Or you can have Trello.NET generate that url using `trello.GetAuthorizationUrl()` but since you're only doing this once, I see no point).

[How to authorize a client (from Trello documentation).](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/authorize.html)